# Looping through features in layer to zoom to feature and export to PNG using ArcPy with ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, data-driven-pages, png

I have a large number of lines in a shapefile representing sites on a map. Each has a unique 2- or 3-digit Id, but they are not consecutive (i.e. 6, 27, 53,... not 1,2,3,...). I want to zoom to each feature in turn and export the map as a PNG file.  I want to save each one as the name of the Id.

I have tried the loop suggested by @Hornbydd but this creates many blank/useless maps for the numbers which are not allocated to sites (i.e. 1,2,3 etc are unneeded), which I had to go through and delete. Note that I cleared the selection before exporting as .png because I don't want the line to show up as highlighted blue.

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
for x in range(6,200):
   arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("sites","NEW_SELECTION",' "Id" = x ')
   df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
   df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
   df.scale=5000
   arcpy.RefreshActiveView
   arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("sites","CLEAR_SELECTION")
   arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, r"X:\site maps\site_" + str(x), "PAGE_LAYOUT", 1280, 960, 160)
```

This worked for the sites I needed but took too long and saved too many useless files.

So then I tried Data Driven Pages:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
for pagenum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
...    mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pagenum
...    ID = <-- what goes here?
...    print "Exporting site {0}, page {1} of {2}".format(str(ID), str(mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID), str(mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount))
...    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, r"U:\Mapping\site_" + str(ID), "PAGE_LAYOUT", 1280, 960, 160)
```

I can't work out what to allocate to ID to get it to be the value in the Id field. I have allocated the Id field as the Name field, but I haven't figured out how to get those values out.

Using

```
...    ID = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageNameField.name
```

sets ID to "Id"

Comment: I think you will find setting a Definition Query may be a more effective way to do this than selecting. There are existing Q&As here that do that.

Comment: Data Driven Pages may be a more manageable approach. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/datadrivenpages-class.htm#C_GUID-7C69EFC8-9C4E-45FA-9482-997A8673E839

Answer (score 3):

Taking your code you need to wrap it up in a loop. The code below assumes you have an ID starting from 1 going to 100.

```py
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
for x in range(1,101):
   arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("sites","NEW_SELECTION",' "Id = ' + str(x))
   df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
   df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
   df.scale=5000
   arcpy.RefreshActiveView
   arcpy.SelectLayerByAttributeManagement("sites","CLEAR_SELECTION")
   arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, r"X:\site maps\img_" + str(x), df, 1280, 960, 160)
```

As a side note, avoid starting file names with numbers.

Comment: Thanks for this!
It has worked for the files within the range. The problem is I don't have all the numbers, consecutively. The first Id is 6, then 27, then 53, so I have ended up with a load of arbitrary files I don't need. Is there a faster way of doing it that creates a loop only with the Ids I have?

Comment: You could use the get count tool to return the number of selected,  if zero then skip