# Looping through features in layer to zoom to feature and export to PNG using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, png

I have a shapefile with a large number of features with consecutive IDs, and I need to zoom in each one and export the map as a PNG file. I found a previous identical question where the code that was suggested is:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
for x in range(1,101):
   arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("sites","NEW_SELECTION",' "Id = ' + str(x))
   df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
   df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
   df.scale=5000
   arcpy.RefreshActiveView
   arcpy.SelectLayerByAttributeManagement("sites","CLEAR_SELECTION")
   arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, r"X:\site maps\img_" + str(x), df, 1280, 960, 160)
```

(From [Looping through features in layer to zoom to feature and export to PNG using ArcPy with ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202889/how-to-loop-through-features-in-a-layer-zoom-to-that-feature-and-export-to-png))

But since I am using ArcGIS Pro "mapping" does not work (apparently need to use arcpy.mp).

What would be the corresponding code for ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 3):

Something along these lines might be a start. I'm still trying to figure out how to set the zoom scale.

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
for x in range(1,7): # I had six features
    arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute('TestFeatures', "NEW_SELECTION", f"OBJECTID = {str(x)}")
    lyt = aprx.listLayouts("*")[0]
    mf = lyt.listElements('MAPFRAME_ELEMENT', "*")[0]
    mf.zoomToAllLayers(x)
    mf.exportToPNG(os.path.join(r"C:\\Test", f"TestFeature_{str(x)}.png"))
```

Comment: I try to run the code but I constantly get OS Error on the last line (no other explanation, just "OSError: [path]"). Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: Change the r"C:\\Test" path to a folder where you want to create the png files. This seems to work but the only thing missing is to zoom into each feature.